# How to fix inherited member hiding warning when dealing with virtual properties

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties, overriding

I have the following base class:

```
public class OAuthRefreshToken {

     //Other properties..

     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public virtual OAuthUser User { get; set; }

}
```

And this derived class:

```
public abstract class OAuthRefreshToken<U> : OAuthRefreshToken 
         where U : OAuthUser {

     public virtual U User { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to override the `User` property from the `OAuthRefreshToken` base class with the one in my derived class.

I thought of adding the `override` keyword:

```
public override virtual U User { get; set; }
```

But this throws a compilation error as it is not allowed.

If I leave the code like that (without override) a **warning** appears saying I'm hiding inherited member (which I intend to do).

It tells me to use `override` if hiding is intended...

And then we are on a nice loop where the warning tells you do something and the compiler tells you not to do it.

Of course, I'll listen to the compiler, but how can I fix the warning? I don't like building my project and have a nice bunch of warnings appear.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the type of the property when overriding it.  If you want to change the type, you need to hide the method instead of overriding it.  If you want to override it instead of hiding it, you'll need to maintain the same type that the base class uses.

Comment: How do I hide the property so I can use my new type? Also note that `U` is an `OAuthUser`

Comment: @MatiCicero You don't use the keyword `override` if you don't want to override the type.  To override the member the property needs to be the *exact same* type, not a derived type.  If `U` is `SomeOtherOAuthUser` what do you expect to happen when someone sets a `DifferentOAuthUser` instance using the base class property setter?

Comment: @MatiCicero: What do you want to happen if someone casts a `OAuthRefreshToken<UserA>` to `OAuthRefreshToken` and assigns a `UserB`?

Comment: @Servy Ok, so I just hide it by not using the `override` keyword. But my question is how do I get rid of the warniing then?

Comment: @MatiCicero You can use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The warning should tell you what you can do - something like this (emphasis mine):

> 'OAuthRefreshToken.User' hides inherited member 'OAuthRefreshToken.User'.
>   To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword.
>   **Otherwise add the new keyword.**

However, presumably you want the two properties to do be about the same value - so you need to *also* override the property from the base class.

Now, there's a problem because you can't have two properties with the same name but different types declared in the same type... so I'd suggest using a different name for the new property - at which point you don't need to declare it with `new` because it doesn't hide anything.

```
public abstract class OAuthRefreshToken<U> : OAuthRefreshToken where U : OAuthUser
{
     public override OAuthUser User
     {
         get { return TypedUser; }
         set { TypedUser = (U) value; }
     }

     public virtual U TypedUser { get; set; }
}
```

I suspect there may be alternatives where you go back to hiding the property if you introduce an intermediate class, but that's almost certainly going to be even uglier.

Comment: Can `OAuthRefreshToken<U>` replace the `OAuthUser User` property from the base class, to an `U User`? I don't want to have the two properties

Comment: @MatiCicero: You're going to have two properties either way, given that they've got different types. You just need to decide whether they've got the same name. Are you sure you need the non-generic base class at all? (And are you sure you need the properties to be virtual?)

Comment: I was actually thinking of using the base class, to use `OAuthUser` as default. And if the consumer of the API would like to use a customized user, then use `OAuthRefreshToken<CustomUser>`. The base class must be no-generic, because otherwise EntityFramework complains.

Comment: @MatiCicero: Ah, you hadn't mentioned EF before. Otherwise I'd have suggested a generic base class with a "simple default" *subclass* using U=OAuthUser.